# Connecting to a Hadoop HDFS within a cloudera virtual machine via IP

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, pentaho, cloudera, kettle

I'm looking to connect to a hadoop instance on a cloudera virtual machine via the server address of the hdfs. Would anyone know how to find the IP address of this?

If not, how could I connect locally to the hdfs within virtual machine, as they are both running on the same computer.

Need to do this for a pentaho kettle connection.

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to configure Pentaho Data Integration (Kettle) to use HDFS as an input data source, then first you'll need to get the hostname/IP address and port number of the HDFS NameNode service, which you will then enter into (Pentaho) Spoon (the GUI to Kettle).

**Getting HDFS NameNode IP/port number**

The default port of the Hadoop HDFS NameNode service is 8020 in both CDH4 and 5 ([source](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera-content/cloudera-docs/CM5/latest/Cloudera-Manager-Installation-Guide/cm5ig_ports_cm.html)).

If for some reason you're not using the defaults, then the hostname/port of the HDFS NameNode service can be found in Cloudera Manager (which should be installed if you're using the Cloudera Quickstart VM, for example):

- Click on the HDFS service on the main Cloudera Manager page
- Click on Configuration - View and Edit
- Click on NameNode - Ports and Addresses.
- "NameNode Port" is the one you want, i.e. not "NameNode Web UI Port". As PDI needs the NameNode port.

**Browse HDFS files in PDI to confirm**

Test by opening Pentaho Data Integration (Spoon) and creating a "Hadoop Copy Files" transformation step, as an example, and then enter in your HDFS details in the "browse files" area and check if a directory list shows up.